# pread() returned only xxx bytes instead of yyy in config file [SOLVED]

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have a little question. I already found a solution, but I want to know the reason for the error.
So, I have a main config file (nginx.conf) that includes vhost configs.
Example hierarchical tree:

```
├── nginx.conf
├── sites_enabled
│   ├── sub.mydomain.com
│   └── sub2.mydomain.com
```

For including vhosts, I use this line:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites_enabled/*;
```

I use two different machines with the same OS and Nginx version. On machine A, it works successfully. But on machine B, I get the following error:

> nginx: [emerg] pread() returned only 614 bytes instead of 632 in /etc/nginx/sites_enabled/sub.mydomain.com

If I rename my subconfigs to `sub_mydomain_com`, for example, it works.

I just want to understand the reasons for this error. So, why do I get this error? Why I get error only on one machine?

Comment: Did you have that config open in your editor?

Comment: @AlexD at same time? not. But I use shared config files in glusterfs space. Both machines use these ones

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pread() read only xxxx of yyyy](https://serverfault.com/questions/547421/pread-read-only-xxxx-of-yyyy)

Comment: @AlexD no. I've already read this question. It's about errors when you've already started nginx and you have problems getting cache files. But I can't start Nginx. And I also tried this solution. Doesn't work

Comment: Then you probably have some file metadata caching issue at GlusterFS level.

Comment: @AlexD probably. But why it works if I rename files without dots?

Comment: The renamed file is a new file so it is not cached.

Comment: @AlexD hmm. I didn't think about this theory before. Need to make another test. I'll try to up same config on a third machine. I will you reply later

Comment: @AlexD  I launched nginx on the third server. It works as expected. So I returned to the second server (where there is an issue). I renamed a file to its old name. and it didn't work again. I renamed it to the new name, and it worked. I repeated the last step. And I got the error: `mv: 'A' and 'B' are the same file`. It seems you're right.